# Redirect deleted posts to category archive

Tags: redirect

I have a website (http://www.ticketyoda.co.uk) and the events listed become outdated after they have been and gone.
I have set it up so that posts automatically expire and are moved to Drafts.

So now I have links which point to the site which are outdated. What I want is the following redirection

```
example.com/1stcategory/2ndcategory/eventABC
```

when it expires

to go to

```
example.com/1stcategory/2ndcategory/
```

This not only makes sense for a user point of view but also as an SEO factor.

I cannot seem to get any plugins to work for me so stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not to move them to drafts. If they are published, then you can check for the event date & then redirect to the appropriate page using the `template_redirect` hook

Comment: Would that solution mean my pages are still indexed and therefore I would have hundreds of outdated pages indexed or would that template_redirect work for google... The main aim is SEO so would this work. thanks

Comment: Make sure to change the header to `301 Permanent Redirect`, then you will be fine

Comment: Il give it a go and let you know. Hopefully I can get it to work automatically.